# Fastest ways to apply formula for a given range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently my main script is appending date from a .csv file once a week. After the data is appended in the sheet I want to add a formula in an extra column, which is using one of the newly appended values in (the dates in the date column) in order to calculate a week number.

I came up with some code, which was supposed to do this, but unfortunately the code is super slow, and since I have thousands of rows my scripts is running out of time before it has even finished with 100-150 rows :/.

This is the code I am currently using :

```
function addWeekNum(firstEmptyRow, dataLength, setupSheet){

  for(i=firstEmptyRow; i<=dataLength;i++){

    setupSheet.getRange("U" + i).setFormula("=WEEKNUM((A" + i + "),2)");

  }

}
```

What is the best way for this to be done? I don't insist it to be done with a script, I just want it to work somehow, but I couldn't figure out how..,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your extra column:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,WEEKNUM(A:A, 2)))
```